# WSOD after installing and setting a customtheme (subtheme of thunder_base)

Tags: wsod

I'm pretty new to Drupal so bear with me pls. I created a customtheme (following standards that "some" guides described) i can install my customtheme from "Appearances" everything worked fine thus far but i have no markup at all on my site it's blank (no error whatsoever) and i can't seem to figure out why (since my info.yml and my libraries.yml seem to be correct containing all the "required" settings). I rechecked all file&directory names and the dir.-structure and everything "seems" to be correct (aside from the fact that i have no markup on my page). I'm using the latest Acquia installation (8.3.7). Any help would be appreciated let me know if i should bring up more information about the issue.
Thanks in Advance.
 I attached my libraries.yml and my info.yml

**dptheme.info.yml**

```
name: dptheme
type: theme
base theme: thunder_base
description: 'all golden and fancy DPtheme.'
package: custom
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - dptheme/global-styling
```

**dptheme.libraries.yml**

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      css/dptheme.css: {}
      css/components/taxonomy-term.css: {}
      css/node-image-field-fix.css: {}
      css/components/tour.theme.css: {}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the error log?

Comment: no errors but a warning that a svg file missing

Answer (score 0):

As the OP answered there was a problem with <strike>folder structure</strike> custom theme files being empty and fixing that resolved the issue.

With this answer though I want to emphasize that Drupal 8 has a well documented theming guide [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming) and also you can find specifics for folder structure [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/drupal-8-theme-folder-structure).

Comment: i actually did not have an issue with the "folder structure" but the template folder containing "empty" twigtemplatefiles overwriting the coretemplates

Comment: Aha...missed a bit of your answer. Editing mine for clarity.

Answer (score -2):

Well i had empty template files in my "custom" templatedirectory so the core templates wouldnt be "applied" (i didnt know about that and no guide mentioning this at all but having me apply a "certain" folder structure with "certain" required files wether they are actually required or not).
So 2 "solutions" either copy/paste the core templates (block.html.twig, node.html.twig etc.) in your template folder or remove the empty twig files (from 
 the custom templatedir so the core templates can be applied). Thx for the help guys !